# MYSQL How to find all records which date is biggest

Tags: mysql

I have following table for storing Instagram details now I want to find all records which date is biggest.

```
Table: instagrammer_recent_statistic

id    instagram_id  comments_count likes_count  created_date
----  ------------  -------------- -----------  ------------
8900  481959735     19             92           2015-11-18 09:46:15
8899  481959735     10             25           2015-11-18 09:46:14
8898  481959735     25             57           2015-11-18 09:46:13
8997  481959735     35             74           2015-11-17 09:46:15
8896  481959735     09             49           2015-11-17 09:46:14
8895  481959735     48             16           2015-11-17 09:46:13
8994  481959735     44             42           2015-11-16 09:46:15
8893  481959735     13             17           2015-11-16 09:46:14
8892  481959735     53             34           2015-11-16 09:46:13
```

And I want to get latest date records which are:

```
id    instagram_id  comments_count likes_count  created_date
----  ------------  -------------- -----------  ------------
8900  481959735     19             92           2015-11-18 09:46:15
8899  481959735     10             25           2015-11-18 09:46:14
8898  481959735     25             57           2015-11-18 09:46:13
```

I have tried with this query but not working properly and getting all results :(

```
SELECT *
FROM instagrammer_recent_statistic
WHERE instagram_id = '481959735' AND
    created_date IN (
        SELECT MAX( created_date )
        FROM instagrammer_recent_statistic
        GROUP BY created_date
    )
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: missing a `WHERE instagram_id = '481959735'` in your inner sql, and can remove the group by

Comment: I have added and run query but not working :(

Comment: Mr. Happy, I have added a SQL Fiddle to my answer and the query appears to be working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query is comparing each `created_date` timestamp against the maximum timestamp.  This will only be true for the record which coincidentally has the max timestamp.  In my query below, I instead compare the *day* of each `created_date` against the *day* from the max timestamp.

```
SELECT *
FROM instagrammer_recent_statistic
WHERE instagram_id = '481959735' AND
    DAY(created_date) = (
        SELECT DAY(MAX( created_date )) FROM instagrammer_recent_statistic
    )
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Click the link below for a running demo of this query using your sample data.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c0c9/2)

Comment: Thanks for your great support :)